# XeLaTeX, unicode-math and Linux Libertine: changing the look of \overrightarrow

Tags: fonts, math-mode, xetex

I am using Linux Libertine and thus far everything has been working flawlessly with regard to the math mode, fonts look very well and match the text perfectly.

However, I found that I do not like the way `\overrightarrow` is typeset, because the tip of the arrow is very big and touches the letters below. I have found somewhere that the solution to that is to use `unicode-math`, which is something I should probably do anyways, and turning it on does indeed solve my issue: the arrow changes the tip to something manageable.

The issue is, `\setminus` disappears; additionally, bold symbols are no longer bold while I do need them for vectors. Therefore, my main question is *how can I get a nicer looking arrow without losing `\setminus` and with working `\bm`* ?

An MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{Linux Libertine}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{bm}
\usepackage{unicode-math}

\begin{document}

Overarrow: $\overrightarrow{u, v}$

Setminus: $U\setminus V$

Vector: $x$, $\bm{x}$

\end{document}
```

EDIT: As @egreg pointed out, the issues with missing `\setminus` are known. However, even when solved, I need **bold** symbols in my equations. `unicode-math` effectively precludes using them, apart from the work-around with `FakeBold`, [see here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/55410/bold-italic-math-with-unicode-math).

Therefore, is there a way of changing the `\overrightarrow` without the use of `unicode-math`?

Comment: See http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/140279/which-fonts-can-be-used-with-unicode-math-package that shows the same problem

Comment: Weirdly, the answer `\renewcommand{\setminus}{\mathbin{\backslash}}` doesn't work in my case. Using a single glyph from Asana works, thanks!

Comment: Unfortunately, using unicode-math also causes a bigger problem: my bold fonts disappear because no bold faces are available now. Is there any way of avoiding unicode-math and still getting a nice arrow?

Comment: I see no bold in the example

Comment: I would keep `libertine`, add the package `amssymb` then use `\smallsetminus`, for some reason with the libertine package smallsetminus closely resembles setminus.

Comment: @egreg: now it's there.

Comment: @doed: that might work, but I am again left without bold letters.

Comment: @Up-and-comingLaTeXMastah why would you be left without bold fonts? Just use `\mathbf`. Please note, I left everything untouched as in your example. I just added the `amssymb` with the `\smallsetminus`. I disagree with egreg's answer in that he chose for you what fonts to have,based in the `bm` package. Of course, regardless of the similarity between the fonts here.

Comment: Would there be a way to select the glyphs from Linux Libertine to be used in math mode? I saw this done in one of the related questions with the help of `mathspec`, but when I used them I messed something up. I will be adding a follow-up question.

Answer (score 2):

Using Latin Modern Math along with Linux Libertine is disputable: they are different fonts.

Notice also that `bm` doesn't work with `unicode-math` (at the moment, work is in progress). But you can use `\mathbfit`.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{unicode-math}
\setmainfont[Ligatures=TeX]{TeX Gyre Termes}
\setmathfont{TeX Gyre Termes Math}
% the redefinition for the missing \setminus must be delayed
\AtBeginDocument{\renewcommand{\setminus}{\mathbin{\backslash}}}

\begin{document}

Overarrow: $\overrightarrow{u, v}$

Setminus: $U\setminus V$

Bold vector: $\mathbfit{x}$

\end{document}
```

[image]

The same with Latin Modern for all the document fonts:

[image]

The same with Linux Libertine for text and Latin Modern for math:

[image]

I see no touching of the arrow, but also visual clash between the text and the math fonts.

Comment: Cool, thanks a bunch! Unless a better answer shows up this will have to do. bm was very useful to me in the past because it was able, for example, to get me bold Greek letters.

You don't see a touching arrow now, but without `unicode-math` the tip is much wider. Regarding clashing of the fonts, I do notice that LM are thinner than LL, so I might try using characters from LL; unfortunately, that leads to spacing issues.

Comment: @Up-and-comingLaTeXMastah Producing a math font compatible with Linux Libertine would be a great achievement.

Comment: I have seen a question [here](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/68564/using-linux-libertine-in-math-mode-with-unicode-math-xelatex?rq=1) discussing setting Linux Libertine fonts for different ranges, but I found that by doing so I accidentally replaced glyphs that I wanted, like the `overrightarrow`. More work needed I guess.