# XeLaTeX and Math Fonts from Main Font

Tags: xetex, fontspec, math-fonts, euler

I would like to use Alegreya font since I like it very much. I'm using XeLaTeX because I want to write the source directly in UTF8.

### (EDITED)

However this font doesn't seem to have math support. As an MWE consider the following:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{unicode-math} 
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont[
  SmallCapsFont={Alegreya SC},   
  ItalicFeatures={SmallCapsFont=AlegreyaSC-Italic},
  BoldFeatures={SmallCapsFont=AlegreyaSC-Bold},
  BoldItalicFeatures={SmallCapsFont=AlegreyaSC-BoldItalic},
  Ligatures=TeX,
]{Alegreya}

\begin{document}
\textsc{Example Document}
This is an example document where I like to put some math:
$$
i \neq \mathrm{i} 
$$
also 
$$
∫ \neq ∑ 
$$  
finally
$$
e^θ = \cos \Re θ + i\sin \Im θ
$$
\end{document}
```

### QUESTIONS

1. I noticed that roman font invoked by `\mathrm` and by operators like `\sin` are taken from Alegreya while the others are standard Computer Modern Math, since is the default choice and I didn't use `\setmathfont`. It is possible to make XeLaTeX use Alegreya Italic in math? How is possible to do it? What are disadvantages in doing this?
2. I noticed that the `Euler` font in LaTeX harmonizes very well with Alegreya. It is possible to use it in XeLaTeX? (I found that the project `Neo Euler` seems inactive.)
3. Would you suggest another math font to use with Alegreya? I tried the standard XeLaTeX math font (STIX, XITS, TeX Gyre Something), which are well designed but do not match well will Alegreya.

Comment: I was able to find just partial answers. Could you send me the some links?

Comment: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/375211/old-math-font-commands-mathrm-etc-and-unicode-math-range-option

Comment: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/238209/general-guide-on-how-to-set-up-minion-pro-for-math-in-lualatex

Comment: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/68564/using-linux-libertine-in-math-mode-with-unicode-math-xelatex

Answer (score 3):

Get `euler.otf` from https://github.com/khaledhosny/euler-otf

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{unicode-math} % loads fontspec

\setmainfont[
SmallCapsFont={Alegreya SC},   
ItalicFeatures={SmallCapsFont=AlegreyaSC-Italic},
BoldFeatures={SmallCapsFont=AlegreyaSC-Bold},
BoldItalicFeatures={SmallCapsFont=AlegreyaSC-BoldItalic},
]{Alegreya}

\setmathfont{Neo Euler}
\setmathrm{Alegreya}
\setmathfont[range=it]{Alegreya-Italic}
\setmathfont[range=bfit]{Alegreya-BoldItalic}
\setmathfont[range={}]{Neo Euler} % empty range to get the correct metrics

\begin{document}

\textsc{Example Document}
This is an example document where I like to put some math:
\[ i \neq \mathrm{i} \]
also 
\[ ∫ \neq ∑ \]
finally
\[ e^z = \cos \Re z + i\sin \Im z \]

\end{document}
```

[image]

If you instead want to use legacy Euler, use this

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{eulervm}
\usepackage[no-math]{fontspec}

\setmainfont[
SmallCapsFont={Alegreya SC},   
ItalicFeatures={SmallCapsFont=AlegreyaSC-Italic},
BoldFeatures={SmallCapsFont=AlegreyaSC-Bold},
BoldItalicFeatures={SmallCapsFont=AlegreyaSC-BoldItalic},
]{Alegreya}

\begin{document}

\textsc{Example Document}
This is an example document where I like to put some math:
\[ i \neq \mathrm{i} \]
also 
\[ \int \neq \sum \] % sorry, no unicode input
finally
\[ e^z = \cos \Re z + i\sin \Im z \]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: What is the difference between '\setmathrm{}' and '\setmatfont[range=up]{}'?

Comment: However the major problem is that greek letter are not shown